continuous function and argmax set
I encountered the following questions. Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R},X \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ be a continuous function.
If$X$ is non-empty and closed then $A =\{x \in X|f(x)\geq f(y) \forall y \in X\}$ is closed.
If $X$ is compact, then $A$ is compact.
I think I should use preimage of a closed set of a continuous function is closed, and if $\max f(x)$ exists then denote it by $M$, then $A =f^{-1}(\{M\})$ is closed. If the maximum value does not exist, then $A$ is empty, so it is closed.
I didn't use closeness here, so I'm wondering what mistake I've made. Also, what about the compact one?

I think the second one is easier. Since $X$ is compact, $f(X)$ is compact. Then it attains maximum, denote by $M$. Then argmax is preimage of ${M}$, which is necessarily closed. And X is compact, a closed subset of compact set is therefore compact. But the first one?

I think the first one should be, we know $A$ is closed relative to $X$, and since $X$ is closed, we have $A$ is closed relative to $\mathbb{R}^k$.
